# Delete non empty directory using find

Tags: fedora, find, delete

I'm trying `sudo find . -type d -name '__pycache__' -delete`
as found here https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode#how-to-install on the trouble shooting page of python-mode. The terminal returns: find: cannot delete 'path' : directory not empty.

Is there a way to work around this. It surprises me this doesn't work as it is literally in the python-mode README.

I'm on Fedora 29 workstation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` option of `find` to use an external command to handle the delete such as `rm -rf`.

Example:

```
sudo find . -type d -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Note: the `{}` is a placeholder for the file path and `\;` ends the `exec` command.
See [man 1 find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
sudo find . -type d -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or work with xargs

```
sudo find . -type d -name 'test' | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This will work with `xargs` as long as you do not have directories with a new-line character in them. Let's say i can create "/home/user/something\n/bin\nanything" If i know that you will run this script it will delete `/bin`. Congratulations you have killed the system.